# BigCommerce checkout display all steps uncollapsed in multiple rows

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to modify the checkout page in our store, this question may be a little incomprehensive for the masters of the BigCommerce league, I apologize for this upfront. Also, similar questions to this question have been asked before but was never answered.

BigCommerce single checkout page (express checkout & optimized single page checkout) comes in multiple collapsed steps, I am trying to un-collapse the containers and make it look like a true single page checkout in three columns instead of steps being underneath each-other.

I know bigcommerce partners are offering similar solutions, I'm trying to find out which panels to modify. I would sincerely appreciate if someone can put a light on which files to modify in order to achieve the goal.

**I can provide access to the staging store if required.**

This is the default checkout_express.html file.

```html
%%Panel.HTMLHead%%
    <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_CdnAppPath%%/javascript/express.checkout.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
        %%Panel.DrawerMenu%%
        <div class="page">
            %%Panel.Header%%
            <div class="main">
                <div class="inner">
                    %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%
                    <div class="Content Widest" id="LayoutColumn1">
                       <!-- <h1 class="TitleHeading mbm">%%LNG_SecureCheckout%%</h1> -->
                    <h1 class="TitleHeading mbm">Secure Checkout</h1>
                        <div class="fullwidth">
                            <div class="Block ExpressCheckout">
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_TPL_PATH%%/js/formfield.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                lang.LoginEnterValidEmail = "%%LNG_LoginEnterValidEmail%%";
                                lang.LoginEnterPassword = "%%LNG_LoginEnterPassword%%";
                                lang.AccountEnterPassword = "%%LNG_AccountEnterPassword%%";
                                lang.AccountPasswordsDontMatch = "%%LNG_AccountPasswordsDontMatch%%";
                                lang.AccountEnterFirstName = "%%LNG_AccountEnterFirstName%%";
                                lang.AccountEnterLastName = "%%LNG_AccountEnterLastName%%";
                                lang.EnterShippingFirstName = '%%LNG_EnterShippingFirstName%%';
                                lang.EnterShippingLastName = '%%LNG_EnterShippingLastName%%';
                                lang.EnterShippingAddress = "%%LNG_EnterShippingAddress%%";
                                lang.EnterShippingCity = "%%LNG_EnterShippingCity%%";
                                lang.ChooseShippingCountry = "%%LNG_ChooseShippingCountry%%";
                                lang.ChooseShippingState = "%%LNG_ChooseShippingState%%";
                                lang.EnterShippingZip = "%%LNG_EnterShippingZip%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAddress = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAddress%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAccountDetails = "Working?";
                                // lang.ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAccountDetails = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAccountDetails%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutLoadError = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutLoadError%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutCheckingOutAsGuest = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutCheckingOutAsGuest%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutCreatingAnAccount = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutCreatingAnAccount%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutChooseBilling = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutChooseBilling%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutChooseShipping = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutChooseShipping%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutChooseShipper = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutChooseShipper%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutFor = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutFor%%";
                                lang.ExpressCheckoutLoading = "%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutLoading%%";
                                lang.ShippingMethodCombined = "%%LNG_ShippingMethodCombined%%";
                                lang.EnterShippingPhone = "%%LNG_EnterShippingPhone%%"
                                lang.EnterCouponCode = "%%LNG_EnterCouponCode%%";
                                lang.BillAndShipToAddress = "%%LNG_BillAndShipToAddress%%";
                                lang.BillToThisAddress = "%%LNG_BillToThisAddress%%";
                                lang.ShipToThisAddress = "%%LNG_ShipToThisAddress%%";
                                lang.CheckingOutAs = "%%LNG_CheckingOutAs%%";

                                var CustomCheckoutFormNewAccount = %%GLOBAL_CustomCheckoutFormNewAccount%%;
                                var CustomCheckoutFormBillingAddress = %%GLOBAL_CustomCheckoutFormBillingAddress%%;
                                var CustomCheckoutFormShippingAddress = %%GLOBAL_CustomCheckoutFormShippingAddress%%;

                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    ExpressCheckout.signedIn = %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutSignedIn%%;
                                    ExpressCheckout.digitalOrder = %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutDigitalOrder%%;
                                    ExpressCheckout.init();

                                    %%GLOBAL_GoToStep%%
                                });

                                %%GLOBAL_FormFieldRequiredJS%%
                                </script>

                                %%Discount.FreeShippingEligibility%%

                                <div class="ExpressCheckoutBlock %%GLOBAL_CollapsedStepClassAccountDetails%%" id="CheckoutStepAccountDetails" style="%%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutHideAccountDetails%%">
                                <p class="ErrorMessage" style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideCheckoutError%%">
                                    %%GLOBAL_CheckoutErrorMsg%%
                                </p>

                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
                                        <a class="ChangeLink" href="#" onclick="return ExpressCheckout.ChangeStep('AccountDetails');" title="Modify"></a>
                                        %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStep%% %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutStepAccountDetails%%: %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepAccountDetails%%
                                        <span class="ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutContent">
                                        <div class="CreateAccount">
                                            <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="ExpressCheckout.GuestCheckout(); return false;">
                                                <div id="CheckoutGuestForm" style="%%GLOBAL_HideGuestCheckoutOptions%%">
                                                    <h4>%%LNG_NotAnExistingCustomer%%</h4>
                                                    <p>%%LNG_CheckoutGuestIntro%%</p>
                                                    <div class="" style="line-height: 2;">
                                                        <dl class="mbm">
                                                            <dd><label><input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_guest" value="guest" type="radio" onclick="$('#BillingDetailsLabel').html('%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAddress%%');" /> %%LNG_CheckoutAsAGuest%%</label></dd>
                                                            <dd><label><input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_register" value="register" checked="checked" type="radio" onclick="$('#BillingDetailsLabel').html('%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAccountDetails%%');" /> %%LNG_RegisterAnAccount%%</label></dd>
                                                        </dl>
                                                        <div class="Submit">
                                                            <input type="submit" id="CreateAccountButton" value="%%LNG_Continue%%" class="btn" /> <span class="LoadingIndicator" style="display: none"><img src="%%GLOBAL_IMG_PATH%%/loader.png" alt="" /></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div style="%%GLOBAL_HideRegisteredCheckoutOptions%%">
                                                    <h4>%%LNG_NotAnExistingCustomer%%</h4>
                                                    <p>%%LNG_CreateAccountIntroTitle%%</p>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <ul style="margin-left: 0; line-height: 1.4; padding-left: 0;">
                                                            <li style="margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;">%%LNG_CreateAccountIntro1%%</li>
                                                            <li style="margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;">%%LNG_CreateAccountIntro2%%</li>
                                                            <li style="margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;">%%LNG_CreateAccountIntro3%%</li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p class="PL40 Submit">
                                                        <input type="submit" value="%%LNG_Continue%%" class="btn" /> <span class="LoadingIndicator" style="display: none"><img src="%%GLOBAL_IMG_PATH%%/loader.png" alt="" /></span>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="AccountLogin">
                                           <!-- <h4>%%LNG_AlreadyHaveAnAccount%%</h4> -->
                                               <h4> What? </h4>
                                            <p id="LoginIntro">%%LNG_AlreadyHaveAnAccountIntro%%</p>
                                            <form action="#" id="LoginForm" method="post" onsubmit="ExpressCheckout.Login(); return false;">
                                                <div class="FormContainer HorizontalFormContainer">
                                                    <p style="display: none" class="ErrorMessage" id="CheckoutLoginError">
                                                        %%GLOBAL_LoginMessage%%
                                                    </p>

                                                    <dl>
                                                        <dt>%%LNG_EmailAddress%%:</dt>
                                                        <dd><input type="text" class="Textbox Field200 InitialFocus" name="login_email" id="login_email" /></dd>

                                                        <dt>%%LNG_Password%%:</dt>
                                                        <dd><input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="Textbox Field200" name="login_pass" id="login_pass" /></dd>
                                                        <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
                                                        <dd>
                                                            <input id="LoginButton" type="submit" value="%%LNG_Continue%%" class="btn" /> <span class="LoadingIndicator" style="display: none"><img src="%%GLOBAL_IMG_PATH%%/loader.png" alt="" /></span>
                                                        </dd>
                                                        <dt></dt>
                                                        <dd><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/login.php?action=reset_password">%%LNG_ForgotYourPassword%%</a></dd>
                                                    </dl>

                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="clear ExpressCheckoutBlock %%GLOBAL_CollapsedStepClassBillingAddress%%" id="CheckoutStepBillingAddress">
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
                                        <a class="ChangeLink" href="#" onclick="return ExpressCheckout.ChangeStep('BillingAddress');" title="Modify">Modify</a>
                                        %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStep%% %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAddress%%:
                                        <span id="BillingDetailsLabel">%%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepBillingAddress%%</span>
                                        <span class="ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutContent">
                                        %%SNIPPET_BillingAddressStepContents%%
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clear ExpressCheckoutBlock %%GLOBAL_CollapsedStepClassShippingAddress%%" id="CheckoutStepShippingAddress" style="%%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutHideShippingAddress%%">
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
                                        <a class="ChangeLink" href="#" onclick="return ExpressCheckout.ChangeStep('ShippingAddress');" title="Modify">Modify</a>
                                        %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStep%% %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutStepShippingAddress%%: %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepShippingAddress%%
                                        <span class="ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutContent">
                                        %%SNIPPET_ShippingAddressStepContents%%
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clear ExpressCheckoutBlock %%GLOBAL_CollapsedStepClassShippingProvider%%" id="CheckoutStepShippingProvider" style="%%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutHideShippingProviders%%">
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
                                        <a class="ChangeLink" href="#" onclick="return ExpressCheckout.ChangeStep('ShippingProvider');" title="Modify">Modify</a>
                                        %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStep%% %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutStepShippingProvider%%: %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepShippingMethod%%
                                        <span class="ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutContent">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clear ExpressCheckoutBlock %%GLOBAL_CollapsedStepClassConfirmation%%" id="CheckoutStepConfirmation">
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
                                        <a class="ChangeLink" href="#" onclick="return ExpressCheckout.ChangeStep('Confirmation');" title="Modify">Modify</a>
                                        %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStep%% %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutStepConfirmation%%: %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepOrderConfirmation%%
                                        <span class="ExpressCheckoutCompletedContent"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutContent">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clear ExpressCheckoutBlock %%GLOBAL_CollapsedStepClassPaymentDetails%%" id="CheckoutStepPaymentDetails" style="%%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutHidePaymentDetails%%">
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutTitle">
                                        %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStep%% %%GLOBAL_ExpressCheckoutStepPaymentDetails%%: %%LNG_ExpressCheckoutStepPaymentDetails%%
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ExpressCheckoutContent">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            %%Panel.Footer%%
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // live change to watch for newly created dom elements
            $('#FormField_11, #FormField_21').live('change',function(){
                $.uniform.restore('select.JSHidden');
            });

        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings) {
            $('select').not('.UniApplied').uniform();
            $('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').not('.UniApplied').uniform();
        });

        $(window).load(function() {
            $('select').not('.UniApplied').uniform();
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Current Checkout Page**:[image: current express checkout]

**Desired Checkout Page**: [image: desired checkout look]

Comment: can you show me your website or screenshot how you would like to see your checkout page steps ?

Comment: Absolutely! The Staging page is located at: http://oguzdev3.mybigcommerce.com

**The original store** is located at: [here](http://www.fleetsafety.com)

I am trying to have the checkout page the same but in a way that we can understand what to modify and which panels do exactly what. 
I appreciate the help!

Comment: Oh also there is a test item I forgot to put the link to:

http://oguzdev3.mybigcommerce.com/test-item/

Comment: as i am checking you enabled your desire checkout instead of steps is it right now?

Comment: The one in our main store, yes we have customized checkout. But it's using the checkout express feature. In the development store, we have the "Optimized One Page Checkout" that has the steps we don't want.